# What steps do I take to access my site's visitor demographics via google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-data

I am making a website for an author who recently finished writing a book.  I want to track the demographics of visitors to a site.  I have heard Google knows an visitor's gender and country as well as age (at least approximately).

My employer (the author) and I would like to track which visitors purchase books and therefore who to target with a marketing campaign in the future.  What steps do I take to access this data?  Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

### First, update your tracker

Now it should looks like:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

And you need this:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

### Enable demographic reports in administration

In Google Analytics select the **Admin tab -> Property -> Demographic and Interests data**.
    In the **PROPERTY** column, click **Property Settings** -> **Advertising Features** -> set **Enable Demographics and Interests Reports** to ON.
    -> **Save**.

### Documentation

**Tech:** https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/display-features
**Admin:** https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2819948?hl=en